# How to left justify index of multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following multilevel df with styles applied:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import rec, nan

a=rec.array([( 0, 'Q1', 'FY20',  0., 'Industry Class Unknown',  748038),
           ( 1, 'Q1', 'FY20', 11., 'Agriculture, Forestry, Fishing & Hunting',    9398),
           ( 2, 'Q1', 'FY20', 21., 'Mining, Quarrying, and Oil and Gas Extraction',   40963),
           ( 3, 'Q1', 'FY20', 22., 'Utilities',    6432),
           ( 4, 'Q1', 'FY20', 23., 'Construction',   22786),
           ( 5, 'Q1', 'FY20', 31., 'Manufacturing I: Food & Textiles',  101826),
           ( 6, 'Q1', 'FY20', 32., 'Manufacturing II: Wood Products, Printing, Chemicals and Plastics',  244901),
           ( 7, 'Q1', 'FY20', 33., 'Manufacturing III: Fabricated Metals, Machinery, Electronics, Furniture, Autos, Aerospace',  676609),
           ( 8, 'Q1', 'FY20', 42., 'Wholesale Trade', 1447690),
           ( 9, 'Q1', 'FY20', 44., 'Retail Trade I: Car Dealers, Recreational Vehicles, Furniture/Appliance/Elecronics/Hardware/Food Stores',  362983),
           (10, 'Q1', 'FY20', 45., 'Retail Trade II: General Merchandise and Online Stores',   60359),
           (11, 'Q1', 'FY20', 48., 'Transportation & Warehousing I: Scheduled Air Transport',  220289),
           (12, 'Q1', 'FY20', 49., 'Transportation & Warehousing I: Warehousing & Storage',   33149),
           (13, 'Q1', 'FY20', 51., 'Information & Publishing',   77937),
           (14, 'Q1', 'FY20', 52., 'Finance and Insurance',  223086),
           (15, 'Q1', 'FY20', 53., 'Real Estate and Rental and Leasing',   58155),
           (16, 'Q1', 'FY20', 54., 'Professional, Scientific, and Technical Services',  226331),
           (17, 'Q1', 'FY20', 55., 'Management of Companies and Enterprises',   88581),
           (18, 'Q1', 'FY20', 56., 'Admin and Support and Waste Management and Remediation Services',   93864),
           (19, 'Q1', 'FY20', 61., 'Educational Services',   23753),
           (20, 'Q1', 'FY20', 62., 'Health Care and Social Assistance',   42256),
           (21, 'Q1', 'FY20', 71., 'Arts, Entertainment, and Recreation',    5574),
           (22, 'Q1', 'FY20', 72., 'Accommodation & Food Services',   35452),
           (23, 'Q1', 'FY20', 81., 'Other Services',   44477),
           (24, 'Q1', 'FY20', 92., 'Public Administration',   59202),
           (25, 'Q2', 'FY20',  0., 'Industry Class Unknown',  790338),
           (26, 'Q2', 'FY20', 11., 'Agriculture, Forestry, Fishing & Hunting',    8931),
           (27, 'Q2', 'FY20', 21., 'Mining, Quarrying, and Oil and Gas Extraction',   14512),
           (28, 'Q2', 'FY20', 22., 'Utilities',    8173),
           (29, 'Q2', 'FY20', 23., 'Construction',   23079),
           (30, 'Q2', 'FY20', 31., 'Manufacturing I: Food & Textiles',  113782),
           (31, 'Q2', 'FY20', 32., 'Manufacturing II: Wood Products, Printing, Chemicals and Plastics',  256295),
           (32, 'Q2', 'FY20', 33., 'Manufacturing III: Fabricated Metals, Machinery, Electronics, Furniture, Autos, Aerospace',  644462),
           (33, 'Q2', 'FY20', 42., 'Wholesale Trade', 1623364),
           (34, 'Q2', 'FY20', 44., 'Retail Trade I: Car Dealers, Recreational Vehicles, Furniture/Appliance/Elecronics/Hardware/Food Stores',  448897),
           (35, 'Q2', 'FY20', 45., 'Retail Trade II: General Merchandise and Online Stores',   76418),
           (36, 'Q2', 'FY20', 48., 'Transportation & Warehousing I: Scheduled Air Transport',  226871),
           (37, 'Q2', 'FY20', 49., 'Transportation & Warehousing I: Warehousing & Storage',   41910),
           (38, 'Q2', 'FY20', 51., 'Information & Publishing',   87441),
           (39, 'Q2', 'FY20', 52., 'Finance and Insurance',  216023),
           (40, 'Q2', 'FY20', 53., 'Real Estate and Rental and Leasing',   61973),
           (41, 'Q2', 'FY20', 54., 'Professional, Scientific, and Technical Services',  229487),
           (42, 'Q2', 'FY20', 55., 'Management of Companies and Enterprises',   68601),
           (43, 'Q2', 'FY20', 56., 'Admin and Support and Waste Management and Remediation Services',   99107),
           (44, 'Q2', 'FY20', 61., 'Educational Services',   26018),
           (45, 'Q2', 'FY20', 62., 'Health Care and Social Assistance',   45278),
           (46, 'Q2', 'FY20', 71., 'Arts, Entertainment, and Recreation',   10018),
           (47, 'Q2', 'FY20', 72., 'Accommodation & Food Services',   39996),
           (48, 'Q2', 'FY20', 81., 'Other Services',   45193),
           (49, 'Q2', 'FY20', 92., 'Public Administration',   60628),
           (50, 'Q3', 'FY20',  0., 'Industry Class Unknown',  791992),
           (51, 'Q3', 'FY20', 11., 'Agriculture, Forestry, Fishing & Hunting',   12382),
           (52, 'Q3', 'FY20', 21., 'Mining, Quarrying, and Oil and Gas Extraction',   14120),
           (53, 'Q3', 'FY20', 22., 'Utilities',    5807),
           (54, 'Q3', 'FY20', 23., 'Construction',   20165),
           (55, 'Q3', 'FY20', 31., 'Manufacturing I: Food & Textiles',  105678),
           (56, 'Q3', 'FY20', 32., 'Manufacturing II: Wood Products, Printing, Chemicals and Plastics',  217225),
           (57, 'Q3', 'FY20', 33., 'Manufacturing III: Fabricated Metals, Machinery, Electronics, Furniture, Autos, Aerospace',  565661),
           (58, 'Q3', 'FY20', 42., 'Wholesale Trade', 1495993),
           (59, 'Q3', 'FY20', 44., 'Retail Trade I: Car Dealers, Recreational Vehicles, Furniture/Appliance/Elecronics/Hardware/Food Stores',  544244),
           (60, 'Q3', 'FY20', 45., 'Retail Trade II: General Merchandise and Online Stores',  103888),
           (61, 'Q3', 'FY20', 48., 'Transportation & Warehousing I: Scheduled Air Transport',  231112),
           (62, 'Q3', 'FY20', 49., 'Transportation & Warehousing I: Warehousing & Storage',   24076),
           (63, 'Q3', 'FY20', 51., 'Information & Publishing',  100013),
           (64, 'Q3', 'FY20', 52., 'Finance and Insurance',  217986),
           (65, 'Q3', 'FY20', 53., 'Real Estate and Rental and Leasing',   52070),
           (66, 'Q3', 'FY20', 54., 'Professional, Scientific, and Technical Services',  200732),
           (67, 'Q3', 'FY20', 55., 'Management of Companies and Enterprises',   70928),
           (68, 'Q3', 'FY20', 56., 'Admin and Support and Waste Management and Remediation Services',   88973),
           (69, 'Q3', 'FY20', 61., 'Educational Services',   20608),
           (70, 'Q3', 'FY20', 62., 'Health Care and Social Assistance',   49326),
           (71, 'Q3', 'FY20', 71., 'Arts, Entertainment, and Recreation',    5718),
           (72, 'Q3', 'FY20', 72., 'Accommodation & Food Services',   35391),
           (73, 'Q3', 'FY20', 81., 'Other Services',   42062),
           (74, 'Q3', 'FY20', 92., 'Public Administration',   59684),
           (75, 'Q4', 'FY20',  0., 'Industry Class Unknown',  515678),
           (76, 'Q4', 'FY20', 11., 'Agriculture, Forestry, Fishing & Hunting',   14242),
           (77, 'Q4', 'FY20', 21., 'Mining, Quarrying, and Oil and Gas Extraction',   11214),
           (78, 'Q4', 'FY20', 22., 'Utilities',    4186),
           (79, 'Q4', 'FY20', 23., 'Construction',   14454),
           (80, 'Q4', 'FY20', 31., 'Manufacturing I: Food & Textiles',   68531),
           (81, 'Q4', 'FY20', 32., 'Manufacturing II: Wood Products, Printing, Chemicals and Plastics',  171972),
           (82, 'Q4', 'FY20', 33., 'Manufacturing III: Fabricated Metals, Machinery, Electronics, Furniture, Autos, Aerospace',  459538),
           (83, 'Q4', 'FY20', 42., 'Wholesale Trade', 1135904),
           (84, 'Q4', 'FY20', 44., 'Retail Trade I: Car Dealers, Recreational Vehicles, Furniture/Appliance/Elecronics/Hardware/Food Stores',  456250),
           (85, 'Q4', 'FY20', 45., 'Retail Trade II: General Merchandise and Online Stores',   77369),
           (86, 'Q4', 'FY20', 48., 'Transportation & Warehousing I: Scheduled Air Transport',  186243),
           (87, 'Q4', 'FY20', 49., 'Transportation & Warehousing I: Warehousing & Storage',   18110),
           (88, 'Q4', 'FY20', 51., 'Information & Publishing',   66377),
           (89, 'Q4', 'FY20', 52., 'Finance and Insurance',  128980),
           (90, 'Q4', 'FY20', 53., 'Real Estate and Rental and Leasing',   32992),
           (91, 'Q4', 'FY20', 54., 'Professional, Scientific, and Technical Services',  122510),
           (92, 'Q4', 'FY20', 55., 'Management of Companies and Enterprises',   57437),
           (93, 'Q4', 'FY20', 56., 'Admin and Support and Waste Management and Remediation Services',   58601),
           (94, 'Q4', 'FY20', 61., 'Educational Services',    9938),
           (95, 'Q4', 'FY20', 62., 'Health Care and Social Assistance',   36879),
           (96, 'Q4', 'FY20', 71., 'Arts, Entertainment, and Recreation',    2270),
           (97, 'Q4', 'FY20', 72., 'Accommodation & Food Services',   16545),
           (98, 'Q4', 'FY20', 81., 'Other Services',   23965),
           (99, 'Q4', 'FY20', 92., 'Public Administration',   33622)],
          dtype=[('index', '<i8'), ('fy_qtr', 'O'), ('fy', 'O'), ('naics_2', '<f8'), ('naics_desc', 'O'), ('quantity', '<i4')])

# Convert array to df
df_final=pd.DataFrame.from_records(a)
df_final.drop(['index'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df_final['metric'] = 'Sales_Volume'

# Pivot df
summary_table = pd.pivot(df_final, index=['metric','naics_2','naics_desc'],columns=['fy', 'fy_qtr'])
summary_table.columns = summary_table.columns.droplevel(0)

# Apply styles

def color_negative_red(x):
    if x <= 0:
      return 'color: red'
    else: 
      return 'color: black'


summary_table=summary_table.style.applymap(color_negative_red).\
                 format('{:,.0f}', subset=('Sales_Volume',)).\
                 set_table_styles([{'selector': '',
                    'props' : [('border','0.1px solid black')]},
                  {'selector': 'th',
                    'props' : [('border','0.5px solid black')]},
                  {'selector': 'td',
                    'props' : [('border','0.5px solid black')]}]).set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'})

summary_table
```

Here is the styled dataframe:

[image]

Question: I want the column (and its title) 'naics_desc' to be left justified with the remaining columns center justified as shown.  Also I would like to hide the multilevel index names 'fy' and  'fy_qtr'.  How would you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

- after `df_final["metric"] = "Sales_Volume"`, insert `df_final["naics_2"] = df_final["naics_2"].astype(int)`
- define two new functions:

```py
def left(v):
    return "text-align: left"


def center(v):
    return "text-align: center"
```

- replace the last blog of your code (beginning with `summary_table=summary_table.style...` with:

```py
summary_table = (
    summary_table.style.set_table_styles(
        [
            dict(selector="th.index_name.level0", props=[("text-align", "center")]),
            dict(selector="th.index_name.level2", props=[("text-align", "left")]),
        ]
    )
    .applymap(color_negative_red)
    .format("{:,.0f}", subset=("Sales_Volume",))
    .set_properties(**{"text-align": "center"})
    .applymap_index(
        left,
        axis=0,
        level=[2],
    )
    .applymap_index(
        center,
        axis=0,
        level=[0, 1],
    )
    .applymap_index(
        center,
        axis=1,
        level=[0, 1, 2],
    )
)
```

- just after, add `summary_table.columns.names = ["", "", ""]`

And so, running `summary_table` in a cell, you get:

[image]

Comment: Wow, looks amazing.  Thanks for the response...

Comment: When I run the code you provided I get an error: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'applymap_index'.  How would I fix this?

Comment: The method is new in Pandas 1.4.0, so be sure to upgrade your version. Cheers.